# fb:app_id Not Updating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to enable moderation with the Facebook comments plugin and I realized I hadn't yet added the following:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{app id}}"/>
```

The Facebook Sharing Debugger was returning the following warning:

> "e 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog."

I added the meta tag (with my correct app id number) to my `index.html` file but the debugger still returns the same warning and my comments plugin still doesn't show the Moderation tab.

It's been hours since I added that meta tag.

Can anyone offer some insight on this issue and/or a solution?

Comment: What is the URL to your page?

Comment: @WizKid I'd prefer not to share the URL. Is this necessary? If you think you could be of help, but need the URL, then perhaps you and I can talk through email or through Skype or something other than this thread. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not some support person unfortunately

Comment: @WizKid, understood. Can you at least explain why you were asking for the URL? If it had to do with you helping out with my question, then I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Because you saying you are doing everything correct. So it is impossible to say what you are doing wrong without looking at what you did

Comment: Are you sure you re-scraped the URL in the debug tool? Also check what the “see exactly what our scraper sees” link at the bottom of the output.